# Move Replication snapshot folder and Distribution database from C to another drive

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am planning to move Replication snapshot folder and Distribution database from C to another drive. Following is what I read blog post.

My setup - Both Distributor and publisher are in same server.

1. Move distribution DB
   Step 1
   Stop SQL agent
   Step 2
   Move MDF & LDF using alter database command
2. Change replication snapshot folder

Step 1
USE distribution
exec sp_changedistpublisher
@publisher = 'XXX',
@property = 'working_directory',
@value = '\New share\Share'
Step 2
Generate a new snapshot for each publication

Do I need to consider anything further.